# Cannot Print a label on Zebra Printer

Tags: java, android, printing

I'm new in Android and I'm trying to understand the right architecture to print files using android. I read about Print Manager, Print service, print job, etc..., but I didn't find a good and simple example from where to start. I did some proof, but I can't get a result.

My target is to print a label or just a string on a Zebra printer. I'm using ip address to connect my app andorid to printer. I found out two example.
The first example:

```
            String ipAddress = "X.X.X.X";
            int port = 9100;
            PrintStream oStream;


            try {
                Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress, 9100);
                oStream = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream(), true, "UTF-8");
                oStream.println("-------------------------------------------------\r\n");
                oStream.println(" NAME     : DEMO CLIENT\r\n");
                oStream.println(" CODE  : 00000234242\r\n");
                oStream.println(" ADDRESS   : Street 52\r\n");
                oStream.println(" Phone : 2310-892345\r\n");
                oStream.println("-------------------------------------------------\r\n");

                oStream.flush();

                oStream.close();
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And second example:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_document_test);

        FONT11 = 10;
        FONT12 = 11;
        FONT14 = 13;
        FONT16 = 15;
        btnCreate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
        editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        btnPrint = findViewById(R.id.btnPrint);
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/impact.ttf");
        gwen = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Gwendolyn-Regular.ttf");

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.orizzontale_nero);
        scaleBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,50,20,false);


        // = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "impact.ttf");
        //carlitoBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "Carlito-Bold.ttf");

        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //new LongOperation().execute(" ");
                new LabelBarcodePDFTask().execute();

            }
        });

        btnPrint.setOnClickListener(v ->{
            new PrintPDF().execute();
        } );

    }

    private class PrintPDF extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
            try {
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(PdfDocumentTestActivity.this.getFilesDir()+ File.separator + "/mypdf/test-ITEXTPDF.pdf");
                InputStream is = fileInputStream;
                clientSocket = new Socket(sIP, Integer.parseInt(sPort));
                outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[3000];

                while (is.read(buffer) != -1) {
                    outToServer.write(buffer);
                }
                outToServer.flush();
                return 1;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

   

    private class LabelBarcodePDFTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String directory_path = PdfDocumentTestActivity.this.getFilesDir()+File.separator + "/mypdf/";
            String targetPdf = directory_path+"test-ITEXTPDF1.pdf";
            //Create layout and set background & borders
            Rectangle layout = new Rectangle(PageSize.ARCH_A);
            //layout.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(100, 200, 180)); //Background color
            layout.setBorderColor(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);  //Border color
            layout.setBorderWidth(6);      //Border width
            layout.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);

            Document document = new Document(layout);
            PdfWriter writer = null;
            try {
                writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(targetPdf));
                document.open();
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
                //Get width and height of whole page
                float pdfPageWidth = document.getPageSize().getWidth();
                float pdfPageHeight = document.getPageSize().getHeight();

                /*document.add(new Paragraph("pdfPageWidth = "+pdfPageWidth));
                document.add(new Paragraph("pdfPageHeight = "+pdfPageHeight));*/

                Barcode39 barcode39 = new Barcode39();
                barcode39.setCode("123456789");
                Image code39Image = barcode39.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
                document.add(code39Image);
                document.newPage();
                document.close();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            return targetPdf;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File saved in "+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Both solution work fine on Brother printer and OKI printer, but when I run on Zebra printer nothing happen.
I ask you if you can provide an example structure to start from. Something simple. Also if there is a way to understand what happens after hitting the print document button

Comment: You should try to send ZPL commands to the printer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've googled some info, one of them about ZPL, but probably   I'm going to use Print Service  "Print Connect", because the first option it's maybe to tricky. What do you think about Print Connect by Zebra?

Comment: Never heard of that service

Comment: Any other suggestion to setup a Zebra printer wifi?